# Regarding GridViews and DateTime columns

Tags: c#, asp.net

The goal of this question is for me to have a better understanding of what exactly is going on.  It seems like there are different ways to solve this issue depending on how the data is coming in.

The situation is that when I pull in data from a stored procedure a lot of times there will be some DateTime columns and at some point I will have to display them on my web page.  Now, depending on how my data is coming in, it seems like I have to use a different solution.  It also depends on if I'm displaying it just inside a label or if I'm displaying it in a GridView.  I would just like to understand what is going on and what the best way to handle this is.

So here are the situations I've run into and what I did to solve the issue (after some researching on this site of course).

**Situation 1:**
DateTime column from a stored procedure being saved into a DataTable and then used as a DataSource for a GridView with AutoGenerateColumns set to false.

My Solution to this situation was to format the date on the ascx page

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SomeDateField", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Situation 2:**
Same as above, except AutoGenerateColumns set to true

My solution was to take care of the formatting on the RowDataBound

```
protected void gvAppraisal_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            AutoGeneratedField field = cell.ContainingField as AutoGeneratedField;
            if (field != null && field.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                cell.Text = DateTime.Parse(cell.Text).ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Situation 3:**  DataColumn from a stored procedure being saved to a DataTable then just using that value inside a label somewhere on my page.

I'm thinking the above method would also work, where I just change the data to a ShortDate, I'll have to do some testing on this later to see.  But I made a helper extension method to handle this as such:

```
public static string ParseFormattedDateFromString(this string dateString, string dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy")
{
    string formattedDate = "";
    DateTime date;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out date))
    {
        formattedDate = date.ToString(dateFormat);
    }
    return formattedDate;
}
```

My third example seems to work well as long as I'm not dealing with a GridView, but when i do use a GridView that solution won't work.  What I would like is a solution that works for all three scenarios.

Now, just from trial and error, is the issue that the gridview is forcing it into a particular date/time format when the datasource is set?  I can't wrap my head around why it seems to work differently when you're dealing with AutoGeneratedColumns vs non AutoGeneratedColumns.

I also looked into solutions for casting those columns to Date, but even though my data looked fine on SQL Server, it was still bringing over the time segment when I ran my program.

Thanks ahead of time for any help with understanding this issue, in the end I'm just trying to grow as a programmer and like knowing what is going on in the background rather than just using a solution that I got to work without knowing what is actually causing it to work.

**Edit**
JaydipJ's solution down in the comments does work well for the situation where I'm making a new stored procedure.  However, most of the time I just have to use a pre-existing stored procedure that I won't be able to make changes to.
--Joseph

Comment: if you need consistent approach, define a model, map your datatable to the list of model, bind that list to GridView;

Comment: @techspider I am not familiar with that approach.  I will have to look that up.

Comment: when you fetching data from db  why not format date there only i.e use `CONVERT(VARCHAR,colName,101)` in sp

Comment: @JaydipJ I'll give that a try, thanks for the tip.

Comment: 101 is for Date Style it ranges from 101 to 114 and 1 to 14

Comment: @JaydipJ I tried to edit my comment, but wasn't fast enough.  I googled it and found the chart for what numbers did what.  I'll give this a try and see what happens, thanks.

Comment: You can also specify the format in the BoundField itself to a degree `<asp:BoundField DataField="field03" DataFormatString="{0:f}" />` See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx for all the datetime options.

Comment: @VDWWD That's good to know, I hadn't had the chance to use a BoundField before, so that might come in handy at some point.